# If then statement with a referenced date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to create an if then statement with a cell referenced date range? For example, currently the formula is working like this, but I don't want to have to update the date in the formula each year. I would rather just change the date in one cell and have the below formula reference that cell rather than "1/1/16" and "12/31/16", but I have been unsuccessful. Thanks for any help!

=IF(AND(D6>=DATEVALUE("1/1/16"),D6<=DATEVALUE("12/31/16")),F6,12)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
=IF(AND(D6>=A1,D6<=B1),F6,12)
```

[image]